# Hide show widget conditionally in form using react-jsonschema-form library

Tags: reactjs, react-jsonschema-forms

I have created a form using below json configuration for react-jsonschema-form

```
{
  "schema": {
    "title": "Employee Detail",
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["name", "email", "country"],
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "Name",
        "default": "",
        "autoComplete": "off"
      },
      "email": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "Email",
        "default": ""
      },
      "registeredAddress": {
        "type": "object",
        "title": "Registered Address",
        "properties": {
          "line1": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Address Line1",
            "default": ""
          },
          "line2": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Address Line2",
            "default": ""
          },
          "city": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "City",
            "default": ""
          },
          "postal": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Postal",
            "default": ""
          },
          "country": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Country",
            "default": "",
            "enum": ["IN", "PK", "CN"],
            "enumNames": ["India", "Pakistan", "China"]
          }
        }
      },
      "isAddressDifferent": {
        "type": "boolean",
        "title": "Is Mailing Address different from Registered Address",
        "default": false
      },
      "about": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "About",
        "default": "",
        "autoComplete": "off"
      }
    },
    "if": {
      "properties": {
        "isAddressDifferent": {
          "const": true
        }
      }
    },
    "then": {
      "properties": {
        "mailingAddress": {
          "type": "object",
          "title": "Mailing Address",
          "properties": {
            "line1": {
              "type": "string",
              "title": "Address Line1",
              "default": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am hiding mailingAddress property on the basis of isAddressDifferent checkbox value, but I want to position mailingAddress on ui after that checkbox and above the about ui widget

Can anyone help me on this?

Below is the codesandbox url for code
https://codesandbox.io/s/rjfs-form-demo-mix96s?file=/src/custom-form/form-config.json